# How can I update column with continuous value by GROUP?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am going to update a table with continuous value based on group.

```
   ItemNo       Group
  ---------------------
   null         group1      
   null         group1     
   null         group2      
   null         group2       
   null         group1      
   null         group2     
   null         group1    
   null         group2      
   null         group1
```

This is an example table.
I am trying to set the ItemNo field with continuous value by Group.
So it will be set like this.

```
   ItemNo       Group
  ---------------------
   1            group1      
   2            group1     
   1            group2      
   2            group2       
   3            group1      
   3            group2     
   4            group1    
   4            group2      
   5            group1
```

I tried with this query by it sets the value without considering Group.

```
DECLARE @id int
SET @id = 0

UPDATE table
SET @id = ItemNo = @id + 1
```

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: You _can't_ generate the exact output you want, because there is no column which provides for the original ordering.

Comment: And what would be the key for updating? Otherwise the DB engine can't tell `(null, 'group1')` from another `(null, 'group1')`

Comment: in the above table, null means it's value is not set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL tables represent unordered sets.  Your assignment seems to depends on the ordering of the rows.  In order to do what you want, you require an ordering column.

If you have one, you can use gaps-and-islands techniques and updatable CTEs:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by group, seqnum - seqnum_g order by <ordering col>) as new_itemno
      from (select t.*,
                   row_number() over (order by <ordering col>) as seqnum,
                   row_number() over (partition by group order by <ordering col>) as seqnum_g
            from t
           ) t
     )
update toupdate
    set itemno = new_itemno;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
;with cte as
(
select *,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by groups order by groups) rn from YOURTABLE
)

update cte set ItemNo=rn
```

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9e2b8c/1)

Comment: Exactly the solution I was going to publish!

Comment: But this updates the table without considering other rows ordering.
For example Id field.